# Increasing a custom view's height in a table view row (and as a result the row's one, too) programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have a view (later, referred as custom view) which renders subviews inside of it. After rendering them out, I get a new required height value (so all subviews will be visible) and try to update the height of the view. Here is the code, called from `awakeFromNib()` method of `UITableViewCell`'s subclass (Note: `ReactiveSwift` is used in the below code):

```
customView.model.requiredHeight.producer
        .observe(on: UIScheduler())
        .skipNil()
        .skipRepeats()
        .startWithValues { [weak self] in
            print("increased Height: ", $0)

            self?.customViewHeightConstraint.constant += $0

            print("customView height: ", self?.customView.frame)
    }
```

So, the correct height to be added to the constraint is grabbed, and the first print statement confirms that. However, this doesn't change view's appearance. The last print statement shows that even I add the value to the view's height constraint, its frame is the same.

I need to mention that this so called custom view is inside a `UITableView`'s row. Here is the layout (the green rect is the cell, the yellow one is a `UILabel` and the red one is the view):

[image]

So, everything is pinned to the edges. I use automatic row height for the row (however, no difference if I set it to custom) and in the table view delegate's `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` method return `UITableView.automaticDimension` as estimated height.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious but can't figure out, honestly. This technique works perfectly if the custom view is not inside a cell, so I think, this has something to do with the table view cell.

Comment: What needs to change is the view’s `intrinsicContentSize`. Also you need to reload the table view or do a batch update to get your change to be seen.

Comment: @matt, such an obvious thing missing, thanks! Actually, just reloading the cell will do, without overriding the `intristicContentSize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done everything right, and your constraints are correct, but the table view has not heard about the fact that they have changed. You need to *reload* the table view (or at least this row).

The best way to do that, by the way, is by performing an empty batch update, because that will cause the change in constraints to be *animated*, which is a very nice look.

**EDIT:** I say "your constraints are correct", but a comment that you later added suggests that this is not true. It sounds like you are trying to "mix and match" fixed layout with autolayout: your custom view uses autolayout, but its subviews do not. Don't do that.

Instead of changing the height constraint of your custom view manually, you should be using constraints internally for all the subviews so that their constraints size the custom view from the inside out — exactly in the same way that the cell itself works. Either that, or you should turn off autoresizing of the cell and implement `heightForRowAt` to dictate the entire cell height *manually*.

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that when subviews are drawn programatically, it is better to turn off  `autoresize subviews` property on both the cell, and the view. Otherwise, those subviews will get stretched, too. Of course, until it is the behaviour needed.

Comment: I've never had the need to do that. I think the problem here is that you actually installed the subviews incorrectly. Instead of changing the height constraint of your custom view manually, you should be using constraints internally for all the subviews so that their constraints size the custom view _from the inside out_.

Comment: Yeah, but these subviews actually don't have any constraints themselves. I am kind of mimicking the behaviour of a collection view with a flow layout, meaning, I add those subviews one after another, and when needed, move to the next line. Based on that, I compute the height of the outer (container) view. I'm just trying to avoid using collection views here.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean you can't give them constraints. — I do understand what you're talking about, however; I've done manual layout of cell subviews too. But if you're going to do that, then you should not be using autosizing of the cell with autolayout; you should be _dictating_ the height of the whole cell with `heightForRowAt`.